# Generating dynamic url based on form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to generate a url based on two drop-down inputs, from currency and two currency such that when a user clicks submit button, the url generated should look like `http://localhost:3000/currencies/usd-eur` when form currency is usd and to_currency is eur for example.

Here's my views(index.html.erb)

```
 <%= semantic_form_for :calculator, :url => {:controller => "conversions", :action => "calculate" }  do |f| %>
      <p><%= f.label :amount %>
      <%= f.text_field :amount %></p>
      <p><%= f.label :from_currency %>
      <%= select :calculator, :from_currency, Choices['from_currency'] %></p>
      </p><%= f.label :to_currency %>
      <%= select :calculator, :to_currency, Choices['to_currency'] %></p>
       <p><%= f.submit "Calculate" %></p>
<%= end %>
```

routes.rb

```
match 'currencies', to: 'conversions#index', via: :get
match 'currencies/convert', to: 'conversions#calculate', as: :calculate, via: :post
```

controller(conversions_controller.rb)

```
def index
 end

 def calculate
  @amount = params[:calculator][:amount]
  @from_cur = params[:calculator][:from_currency]
  @to_cur = params[:calculator][:to_currency]
  @result = ConversionsHelper.calculate(@from_cur, @to_cur, @amount)
 end
```

I don't have any models for that matter since I get my data from google API hence I could be going outside the boundaries of RESFFUL conventions. A detailed answer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have never tried dynamic routing like this but have you looked at `map.connect`?

Comment: Is Conversion a model class?

Comment: conversions is not a model Swards. I'm using google API as my source and parse the values directly without storing them a db. As for engineersmnky, I haven't tried that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This javascript code ended up solving my problem.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Cal').attr('action', '/currencies');
        $("#Cal").submit(function(e){            
            var from = $('#calculator_from_currency').val().toLowerCase();
            var to = $('#calculator_to_currency').val().toLowerCase();
            var url_end = from + "-" + to;
            var url = $('#Cal').attr('action') + '/' + url_end;
            $('#Cal').attr('action', url);            
        });
    });
```

Then I added this line in my routes.

```
  post '/currencies/:url' => 'conversions#calculate', via: [:post]
```

Answer (score 1):

try using jquery, to pick your values from the form.
then set the url by

```
 $('form#currency_form').attr('action', url);
```

in side your form

### update

in your routes file use these routes:

```
match '/currencies/', to: 'converter#show',   via: [:post]
  post '/currencies/:url_end' => 'converter#show'
```

i hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is a bit outside of restfull and rails conventions. You should eventually learn these as they were developed by people who have been doing this a long time and they will make your life a-lot easier. It seems like your just having fun though so here is some coffee script that will do the job.

```
jQuery ->
  currency_convert_path = ->
    "/currencies/#{$(#id_of_from_currency option:selected).val()}-#{$(#id_of_to_currency option:selected).val()}"

  %("#id_of_from_currency #id_of_to_currency").blur( ->
    $("#id_of_form").attr('action', currency_convert_path())
  )
```

You will need to inspect element on your form and fill in the id_of_from_currency id_of_form and id_of_to_currency to the actual ids. Then when you change your selects you can inspect the form before submit and see your new action.

I am also assuming that the value of the option tags are formated like usd and eur. If not you will either need to change them for the above code to have the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks Tyrel. My goal is a bit outside restful as you've said since I use google API as my source and directly parse the values without having to store them on db. I've tried the coffee script but it seems not to work. Could the problem be my routes because it still routes to http://localhost:3000/currencies/convert

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) This is the error I get Richey. I can't figure out where the syntax problem is. Please help.

Comment: You're missing quotes inside the `$()` calls inside the string interpolation.

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected MATH is the new error that seems to be comming from the second part of the coffee script. Here's my new code. jQuery ->
  currency_convert_path = ->
    "/currencies/#{$('#calculator_from_currency option:calculator[from_currency]').val()}-#{$('#calculator_to_currency option:calculator[to_currency]').val()}"

  %("#calculator_from_currency #calculator_to_currency").blur( ->
    $("#Cal").attr('action', currency_convert_path())
  )

Comment: The big question here is how do I route?

Comment: Well the coffee script should be updating your forms action which is where it either puts or posts to. Change your select boxes then inspect element on your form. Does the action update? Check the console is their any java-script errors. Do you have a live version somewhere?

Comment: @Tyrel I solved the problem. Here's a link to the live version http://aqueous-caverns-9302.herokuapp.com/currencies

Answer (score 0):

Ahh like mu is too shor said sorry I made a boo boo

Change

```
"/currencies/#{$(#id_of_from_currency option:selected).val()}-#{$(#id_of_to_currencyoption:selected).val()}"
```

to

```
"/currencies/#{$('#id_of_from_currency option:selected').val()}-#{$('#id_of_to_currency option:selected').val()}"
```

Notice the '' inside the $()'s